Use custom property names when generate POJO from jsonschema
I have following schema definition
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
"title": "Book"
type: object
properties:
  f1:
    type: string
  f2:
    type: integer

I would like to generate POJO like:
public class Book{
  @JsonProperty("f1")
  private String title;
  
  @JsonProperty("f2")
  private Integer length;

  //getters, setters etc.
}

Problem is, that field names in schema are not human readable and I want to convert them while generating and preserve original names in @JsonPropery annotation.
I found a tool jsonschema2pojo, that has also a maven plugin - it's great, but I haven't found a way to add name conversion.
Note:
I found one can use "description" or add custom field property to specify the name in schema and use custom annotator for jsonschema2pojo and change field name, but generated getters, setters, builders still use the original non-human readable name.
Any ideas how to solve the problem? it can be another tool than jsonschema2pojo as long as it can generate Java code from json/yaml schema during during build as maven plugin.

"yamlschema" isn't a thing, exactly. It's just JSON Schema, but written in yaml.

I know, I just prefer yaml format for readability and I know jsonschema2pojo supports both. But if you know answer to my question, that supports only jsonschema in json I am fine with that

"I just prefer yaml format for readability..." This is fine, but it's still called "JSON Schema".  There's not a thing called "yamlschema".

I don't have an answer.  You might have better luck with opening an issue in the repo for that project.
